# Number of equivalence classes of a proper subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $(G,+)$ be a group of order $2019$. How many equivalence classes does a proper subgroup of $G$ of order at least $100$ generate? Justify your answer.

**EDIT**: The solution involves Lagrange's theorem:

$|G|=|H|\cdot|G:H|$

$|H|=673$

Therefore, the number of equivalence classes is $|G:H|=3$.

Comment: Yep, I think this is the intended approach. There is only one possible order  $\geq 100$ for a proper subgroup of $G$.